# BSc Hons and MRPHARMS on business cards after names

Tags: titles, bachelor, professional-association, business-card

I am about to have cards of introduction made.
Should both Bsc Hons and MRPharms be added after my name or just MRPharms to reflect I have a pharmacy degree and also have a membership of the Professional Body Royal Pharmaceutical Society of Great Britain?

Comment: This is a very local thing. How are other pharmacists doing? go with the flow.

Comment: Who will these cards be given to?  Potential customers of your pharmacy? (include only MRPharms) Acquaintances of your parents whom you wish to impress?  (include as much as possible)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

On a business card there are other ways to provide this information than with abbreviations following your name.

For example, a line or two at the bottom of the card showing such things as the degree with honors and/or memberships can suffice. A more concise listing of your name could even be an advantage and less confusing for some. Think about the information as a whole and how it is best presented on the card.